# How to remove indentation of code in ckeditor on submit the form

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor, email-templates

I have email templates in admin panel. The email template is shown in ckeditor. The html code of email template is in compressed form. The issue is when i make some changes in email template from ckeditor the html code return me in indentation. with indentation my email templates design looks not good. I have config file like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
    config.tabSpaces = 0;  };
```

Can anyone tell me what i mistake in config file. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This should disable indentation:

```
CKEDITOR.config.dataIndentationChars = '';
```

Documentation: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-dataIndentationChars